# subtle patterrns background iOS png files

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm developing a universal app and I wanted to use some of the backgrounds found on subtlepatterns.com and on downloading them I'm only seeing two png files (regular png & 2x png). How do I use them both for iPhone and iPad (including retina displays)?. Do I have to scale them to support all resolutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a pattern as the background color for your views. It won't matter what the size of the view is and the retina version will be chosen automatically if you include both files in your project. For example:

```
UIImage *bgimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gray_jean"];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:bgimg];
```

And if you have 2 files in your project:

```
gray_jean@2X.png
gray_jean.png
```

It should work in any situation; the image will be tiled to fill any view background and the retina version used automatically for retina screens. Be careful though because in some of those patterns the non-retina version is a PNG file while the @2x retina version is a JPEG file.

Comment: Good call. What about for iPad (including retina) as another user has explained below?

Comment: Because you're tiling an image to create a background color, it won't matter. It'll fill a view's background whatever the size.

Answer (score 1):

There's no additional scaling to be done because the patterns should be tiled (and you have the regular and @2x versions). Assuming you have `pattern.png` and `pattern@2x.png`, here's a simple way to tile the image.

```
UIColor *pattern = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pattern"]];
[myViewController.view setBackgroundColor:pattern];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to use different images for iphone and ipad and for different images for retina display. If you use iphone images for ipad or retina display it'll displayed as pixelated.

So make sure you use the exact resolution image for each type.

Please check the apple's doc for the resolution details.

[**Apple Image resolutions**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)

[image: Resolution images]